# Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError when stylesheet_packs_with_chunks_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I'm having issues making `= stylesheet_packs_with_chunks_tag('application', media: 'all')` work on my development environment.

If I use plain `javascript_pack_tag` it's working but not using chunks.

Here's my `webpacker.yml`

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2
    - .cur

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg
    - .cur

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "rukiasites",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.2-2",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.9.0",
    "easy-autocomplete": "^1.3.5",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "jquery-parallax.js": "^1.5.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

`environment.js`

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack         = require('webpack')
const customConfig    = require('./custom')

environment.config.merge(customConfig)

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $:      'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
)

environment.splitChunks()

module.exports = environment
```

`development.js`

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

Yarn install was successful, as well as the compilation via `webpack-dev-server`. The `/public/packs` and `manifest.json` aren't empty. I'm trying to run an existing app that's why I couldn't upgrade the versions to latest. The current versions or setup work well on others. Am I missing anything?

EDIT: Btw, Rails version is 6.0.2.2, Node v is v8.17.0 and Yarn is 1.22.4

Comment: Do you have an `application-........chunk.css` file inside your `public/packs/css` folder?

Comment: @arieljuod oops looks like none. Sorry, I'm new to webpack. Is there a way to debug or to understand why it's not generated? B/c I haven't seen any errors when webpack dev server is compiling.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `stylesheet_packs_with_chunks_tag`? on the next line you mention `javascript_pack_tag` as a replacement, maybe you want `javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag`?